# How to spawn objects in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a flappy bird like game and I am trying to spawn enemy birds and gold coins so I have written the C# code and the made the prefabs, but when I run the bird and the coins are not respawning.

This is the respawn code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject GameObjectToSpawn;
    private GameObject Clone;
    public float timeToSpawn = 4f;
    public float FirstSpawn = 10f;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        FirstSpawn -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (FirstSpawn <= 0f)
        {
            Clone = Instantiate(GameObjectToSpawn, gameObject.transform.localPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            FirstSpawn = timeToSpawn;

        }
    }
}
```

screenshot of unity:
[image]

This where i am respawning the first enemy bird:

[image]

Comment: From your code I don't see why it shouldn't ... you run this in PlayMode right? ^^ Do you get any errors in the console? Btw you can get rid of the `as GameObject` .. `Instantiate` anyway returns the type of the given prefab. Also be aware that this will always overwrite the `Clone` field .. in case you need them all rather use e.g. a `List<GameObject>` ... Is it possible you destroy the object referenced in `GameObjectToSpawn` on runtime?

Comment: It probably is cloning but are you setting the position of the new object to the original objects position and nothing more? Where are you expecting this new object to appear?

Comment: @derHugo, i do not have any errors in the console.It is not respawning the birds or the coins after given the time also

Comment: Can you see the FirstSpawn value decreasing in the Inspector?

Comment: @Charleh, i have set the enemySpawn at 3 places at the top, middle and bottom, that is where i am expecting it to spawn

Comment: why "localPosition" instead of Position?

Comment: @derHugo, yes, i can see the FirstSpawn value decreasing

Comment: @jai from your new screenshot: It seems to be spawned but way off the screen .. you can literally see the little micro island in the bottom left corner .... is it really supposed to be there? Did you try rather placing it where it actually should be spawned and use `transform.position` for the `Instantiate` instead?

Comment: @derhugo, yes, that is where i went wrong, it was way of the screen, i changed it now and it is spawning. Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your second screenshot it seems to be spawned but way off the screen! You can still see the tiny little island in the bottom left corner.

You thought seems to be that you have to spawn it in the Canvas pixel space using the spawn point's `localPosition`. But this is not the case since `Instantiate` places it into the scene root (without any parent) with absolute world-space position into the scene.

You should rather actually place the spawn point to the absolute world position where the spawn should happen and rather use

```
Clone = Instantiate(GameObjectToSpawn, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Btw no need for the `as GameObject` since [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) already returns the type of the given prefab.